# How to write AWS lambda function to handle docker webhook

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, dockerhub

I am trying to write an AWS Lambda function to handle a dockerhub webhook response.

I have the code that I've modified from AWS Lambda Cloudformation Examples, and I was able to get a Response 200 after sending the POST request back to the webhook respons_url, but the webhook process did not actually complete.

Am I missing anything here?
Could someone please shed some light on this?

Here it the function

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {

     console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED:\n", JSON.stringify(event));

     sendResponse(event, context, "SUCCESS");

};
function sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData) {
    var responseBody = JSON.stringify({
       state: responseStatus,
       description: "Build ECS Description",
       context: "Build ECS Context",
       target_url: event.callback_url
     });

    console.log("RESPONSE BODY:\n", responseBody);

    var https = require("https");
    var url = require("url");

    var parsedUrl = url.parse(event.callback_url);
    var options = {
       hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
       port: 443,
       path: parsedUrl.path,
       method: "POST",
       headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Accept": "Application/json"
       }
   };

   var request = https.request(options, function(response) {


       console.log("STATUS: " + response.statusCode);
       console.log("HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
       // Tell AWS Lambda that the function execution is done  
       context.done();
   });

   request.on("error", function(error) {
       console.log("sendResponse Error:\n", error);
       // Tell AWS Lambda that the function execution is done  
       context.done();
   });

   // write data to request body
   request.write(responseBody);
   request.end();
}
```